# Split markdown snippet when headers come

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I have the following snippet of markdown:

```
# Glossary

This guide is aimed to familiarize the users with definitions to relevant DVC
concepts and terminologies which are frequently used.

## Workspace directory

Also abbreviated as workspace, it is the root directory of a project where DVC
is initialized by running `dvc init` command. Therefore, this directory will
contain a `.dvc` directory as well.

## Cache directory

DVC cache is a hidden storage which is found at `.dvc/cache`. This storage is
used to manage different versions of files which are under DVC control. For more
information on cache, please refer to the this
[guide](/doc/commands-reference/config#cache).
```

I want to split it such that there are there matches which should be:

```
# Glossary
...
```

```
## Workspace directory
...
```

```
## Cache directory
...
```

I tried to match them using regex `/#{1,2}\s.+\n{2}[^(#{2}\s)]*/`. My intention was to match the heading first with this part `#{1,2}\s.+\n{2}` and then terminate matching when `##\s` is found. But I'm failing with the second part. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Why not use split? `s.split(/^(?=#)/m).filter(Boolean)`. Or the regex that requires a space after `#` is `/^(?=#+ )/m`

Comment: something like `#{1,2}[a-zA-Z\s\[\](-.,\`/\n]+` is almost there. the trick would be to start with `#{1,2}` and detect everything until `\n#` is detected. but for some reason `(?=\n#)` doesnt work

Comment: `#{1,2}[^#]*` and `#{1,2}\s[^#]*` are almost there too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` with `/^(?=#+ )/m` regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kojMUJ/1)) or match with `match(/^#+ [^#]*(?:#(?!#)[^#]*)*/gm)` (see [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/i56l2Y/1)):

```js
let contents = `# Glossary

This guide is aimed to familiarize the users with definitions to relevant DVC
concepts and terminologies which are frequently used.

## Workspace directory

Also abbreviated as workspace, it is the root directory of a project where DVC
is initialized by running \`dvc init\` command. Therefore, this directory will
contain a \`.dvc\` directory as well.

## Cache directory

DVC cache is a hidden storage which is found at \`.dvc/cache\`. This storage is
used to manage different versions of files which are under DVC control. For more
information on cache, please refer to the this
[guide](/doc/commands-reference/config#cache).`;

console.log(contents.split(/^(?=#+ )/m).filter(Boolean));
console.log(contents.match(/^#+ [^#]*(?:#(?!#)[^#]*)*/gm));
```

Output:

```
[
  "# Glossary\n\nThis guide is aimed to familiarize the users with definitions to relevant DVC\nconcepts and terminologies which are frequently used.\n\n",
  "## Workspace directory\n\nAlso abbreviated as workspace, it is the root directory of a project where DVC\nis initialized by running `dvc init` command. Therefore, this directory will\ncontain a `.dvc` directory as well.\n\n",
  "## Cache directory\n\nDVC cache is a hidden storage which is found at `.dvc/cache`. This storage is\nused to manage different versions of files which are under DVC control. For more\ninformation on cache, please refer to the this\n[guide](/doc/commands-reference/config#cache)."
]
```

[Regex #1 (splitting) graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3D%23%2B%20)):

[image]

Regex #2 (matching) graph:

[image]

Comment: @BugWhisperer How doesn't it work? It only demonstrates where the regex matches and splits will occur. What do you expect the demo of a *regex* to show?

Comment: i misunderstood the purpose of the demo

Comment: how could i alter `#{1,2}[^#]*` so that it matches anything but `##`?

Comment: @BugWhisperer Perhaps, `#{1,2}[^#]*(?:#(?!#)[^#]*)*`, see https://regex101.com/r/Ii3dK7/1. But it won't be a good solution here, see https://regex101.com/r/0cRPiP/1 where it breaks

Comment: thanks i will check out all of it tomo when i wake up.

Comment: is there no way to detect line breaks? `\n` doesnt seem to be working as i would expect it to

Comment: @BugWhisperer No idea what you mean. There is no `\n` anywhere in my regex.